# C# html agility pack not getting unique content in a loop

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape a website for articles, the title, and the URL to the full article. In my loop, i keep getting the same title for each run, but my URL is unique and working. What am I missing/doing wrong? Is the wrong approach?

```
// List
var content = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/article").ToList();

foreach (var article in content)
{

    // Get news title
    string articleUrl = article.SelectSingleNode("a").Attributes["href"].Value;
                
    // Get url to full content
    string articleTitle = article.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='dre-item__alt-title--md']/div").InnerText;


    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", articleTitle);
    Console.WriteLine("Url: {0}", articleUrl);
    Console.WriteLine("--------");

}
```

Output,

```
Title: R&#xF8;kkes krillselskap guider 2,5-gangeren
Url: /nyheter/teknologi/2021/02/14/7625196/intel-utfordreren-ascenium-har-steget-36-pa-tre-uker
--------
Title: R&#xF8;kkes krillselskap guider 2,5-gangeren
Url: /nyheter/bors/2021/02/16/7626652/dnb-markets-aksjemarkedet-responderer-positivt
--------
Title: R&#xF8;kkes krillselskap guider 2,5-gangeren
Url: /nyheter/shipping/2021/02/15/7625988/kepler-cheuvreux-oker-kursmalet-pa-golden-ocean-group
--------
Title: R&#xF8;kkes krillselskap guider 2,5-gangeren
Url: /leder/2021/02/09/7622385/elon-musk-og-andre-spekulanter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XPath expression starting with a `/` starts from the root, even when you call it on a subnode.
Start the expression with `.//` to start from that "article" node.

Comment: Thanks! didn't know that. Got it working now by setting up the xpath correcntly.